# How to unmount screen on blur in a StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

Im using **React Navigation x5**, I have `StackNavigator` that's loading bunch of screens. I want to unmount one particular screen component on blur to get the same result of using `unmountOnBlur` when using a `DrawerNavigator`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9):

There are currently three ways to do it since `5.x`. You can either

- use `useFocusEffect` hook to trigger an action (recommended), or
- use `useIsFocused` hook, or
- listen to the `focus` event

###### Example of `useFocusEffect`

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Sample(props) {
  const [shouldHide, setShouldHide] = React.useState(false);

  useFocusEffect(() => {
    setShouldHide(false)
    return () => {
       setShouldHide(true)
    }
  });

  return shouldHide ? null : <InnerComponent {...props} />;
}
```

###### Example of `useIsFocused` hook

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile() {
  // This hook returns `true` if the screen is focused, `false` otherwise
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return {isFocused ? <Text>Inner component</Text> : null};
}
```

Note:

> Using this hook component may introduce unnecessary component re-renders as a screen comes in and out of focus. ...
> Hence we recommend to use this hook only if you need to trigger a re-render.

More information can be found in the documentation [Call a function when focused screen changes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/)

---

Besides that, stack navigators come with a prop called `detachInactiveScreens` which is enabled by default. [Link to the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#detachinactivescreens)

> [`detachInactiveScreens`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#detachinactivescreens)
>
> Boolean used to indicate whether inactive screens should be detached from the view hierarchy to save memory. Make sure to call `enableScreens` from `react-native-screens` to make it work. Defaults to `true`.

(The instruction on enabling React Native Screens can be found at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/react-native-screens/#setup-when-you-are-using-expo)

Inside the stack navigator's `options` object, there is also a `detachPreviousScreen` prop to customise the behaviour of certain screens. This option is usually enabled as well.

> [`detachPreviousScreen`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#detachpreviousscreen)
>
> Boolean used to indicate whether to detach the previous screen from the view hierarchy to save memory. Set it to `false` if you need the previous screen to be seen through the active screen. Only applicable if `detachInactiveScreens` isn't set to false. Defaults to `false` for the last screen when `mode='modal'`, otherwise `true`.